# How can I fix this entry door light?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I've got this going on. Can anyone take me through the steps on how to fix this situation?

Edit: Alright I got up there with a ladder and took this video. Can anyone take a look at the video and give me a prescription of what I need to do?

**YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvz3dsbG0a0&feature=youtu.be**

Picture:

[image]

Comment: I don't get whats going on here.. is the entire fixture/box inside the ceiling? how far does that bulb stick out?

Comment: I'll get up there tomorrow with a ladder and see if I can get a better picture. I'm pretty sure the light is just hanging their by a wire.

Comment: It looks like the fixture is above the ceiling and steelwool is stuffed in the hole to keep bugs out, is this a good description of the problem?

Comment: And what is the ceiling material? The hole looks larger than a normal junction box, so some ceiling repair may be in order.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to tell what's going on here, from just that picture. You're going to have to get up there and investigate, just be careful and turn off the power to the light first.  Also... If that is steel wool, you should remove it immediately. [Electricity + steel wool = fire](https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/RXC21JM6O30?start=146&end=149&version=3&autoplay=1)

Comment: How do I reopen the question? I updated the question with a video closeup of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the video you provided, it looks like a recessed light fixture that is missing the trim.

You should try to find some identifying marks on the inside of the fixture and then find a compatible outdoor trim.